# Encryption of an input with Caesar Cipher in Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I have to write this code where The function must receive a path to a text file which must contain text composed of only English letters and punctuation symbols and a destination file for encrypted data. Punctuation symbols must be left as they are without any modification and the encrypted text must be written to a different file.
Also, I have to validate the inputs.

I've done most of it but in the first part, where I have to ask for a text, the code isn't accepting spaces or punctuation marks, and as I gather it's because of `.isalpha`, however I couldn't find a way to fix it.

I'm not sure if I have completed the aforementioned requirements, so any type of feedback / constructive criticism is appreciated.

```
  while True:   #  Validating input text
    string = input("Enter the text to be encrypted: ")
    if not string.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a valid text")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:  #  Validating input key
    key = input("Enter the key: ")
    try:
        key = int(key)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid key: ")
        continue
    break


def caesarcipher(string, key):   #  Caesar Cipher
    encrypted_string = []
    new_key = key % 26
    for letter in string:
        encrypted_string.append(getnewletter(letter, new_key))
    return ''.join(encrypted_string)


def getnewletter(letter, key):
    new_letter = ord(letter) + key
    return chr(new_letter) if new_letter <= 122 else chr(96 + new_letter % 122)


with open('Caesar.txt', 'a') as the_file:  # Writing to a text file
    the_file.write(caesarcipher(string, key))

print(caesarcipher(string, key))
print('Your text has been encrypted via Caesar-Cipher, the result is in Caesar.txt')
```

Comment: A good idea is to make an abstraction of the problem and isolate the problematic part (in your case filtering the input). As it is you should address the question to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This can be done with a _regex_ or using a character per character approach: it could be useful the `string` package, `string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation`. Notice that your concept of punctuation may include other characters, so check it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could check it "manualy".

```
# ____help_function____
def check_alpha(m_string):
   list_wanted = ['!', '?', '.', ',']

   for letter in m_string:
      if not (letter in list_wanted or letter.isalpha()):
         return False

   return True

# ____in your code____
while True:
   string = input("Enter the text to be encrypted: ")

   if check_aplha(string):
      break
   else:
      print('....')
```

Comment: I believe this has solved the validating part! as it turns out, the final code is `def check_alpha(m_string):
   list_wanted = ['!', '?', '.', ',', ' ']
   for letter in m_string:
      if not (letter in list_wanted or letter.isalpha()):
         return False
   return True
while True:
   string = input("Enter the text to be encrypted: ")
   if check_alpha(string):
    break
   else:
      print('Please enter a valid text: ')
   continue
   break`    However, the final break is for some reason unreachable. Thank you very much @JohnyCapo

Comment: @Juj I would add `' '` spacebar into list_wanted... Because spacebar is not alpha either inside the list.

Comment: This solution will not work if all the characters are punctuation. how you accept it when it's against your criteria.

Comment: Yes, I have done that already after testing it a couple times, also, please let me know if you have any idea regarding the other part. (The function must receive a path to a text file which must contain text composed
of only English letters and punctuation symbols and a destination file for encrypted data) because I'm not sure if my code does exactly that. Once again, thank you @JohnyCapo

Comment: check for this test case `.?!.,` it will accept input.

Comment: @Oghli , I never mentioned that yours doesn't work sir, but what JohnyCapo had written was just a bit more understandable. I apologize if me not accepting your solution offends you in any way.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you accept my solution or not. this code isn't working right for the criteria you mention it why did you accept it.

Comment: Well it is easily solved by `return True and any(letter.isalpha() for letter in m_string)` at the last row inside function.

Comment: because at first few tests it had solved the problem I was facing. I don't think there will be any input for this code where all of it are just punctuations, since the whole idea of the code is to encrypt texts while leaving punctuations untouched.

Comment: But as you said @Juj I did not think that there will be situations like `.?` sentence. :) Please, create a new problem @Juj for the next part and we can solve it right there. We should not solve multiple problems inside one thread.

Comment: you should be consistent with requirements of your program when you are asking question on SO and in specific case how the input should be accepted.
You mentioned in the comments that you doesn't accept input if only contains punctuation, also if one of the characters is special symbols other than punctuation characters.

Comment: @JohnyCapo my friend no hard feeling it doesn't matter for me if he accept your solution or not. but he should be clear about how he wants the program to work when he ask a question.

Comment: @Juj check this reference on how to ask good question:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can validate input string by checking if it doesn't contain any Alphabet characters then it's invalid input:

```
import string

def check_valid_input(str):
    for c in str:
        if not c.isalpha() and (c not in string.punctuation):
            return False
    return True and any(c.isalpha() for c in str)
     

while True:   #  Validating input text
    string = input("Enter the text to be encrypted: ")
    # checking if contain only alphabet characters and punctuations
    if not check_valid_input(string): 
        print("Please enter a valid text")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

In this way you only accept input string if there are alphabet characters and doesn't contain any special characters(other than punctuation) in it.

Comment: So in this way I could just input random **A$ß¤>*!"** etc... And it would still end as `break` because there was an **A** init... This goes against all Cipher logic.

Comment: @JohnyCapo yes because it contains alphabet character in it, if it is like `$ß¤>*!` without any English letter it will be invalid input.

Comment: But she/he is seeking of alphabet with **punctuation symbols**. That contains `?!.,`. So any other has to be `declined`. That is what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: @JohnyCapo how do you want it to check the input. what the criteria you want for validating the string.

Comment: @JohnyCapo check my updated solution it should work for your case now. it doesn't accept any input with special characters other than punctuation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249783/discussion-between-johnycapo-and-oghli).